# Find the length of the curve from x=-2 to x=1 of $y=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$

Tags: calculus

Homework problem I recently got:

> Find the length of the curve of $y=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$
>   from $x=-2$ to $x=1$. Also find the area of the surface of revolution about the $x$-axis.

Having trouble understanding this.  I'm not even sure what it would look like.  I assume a is supposed to be a constant.  Is it just a semi-circle with radius $a$.  $X$-intercepts of $(-a,0)$ and $(a,0)$ and a max at $(0,a)$?

I'm a little iffy about how to first find the length.

I do know that I should start with $\int_{-2}^{1} 2\pi y ds$ since I am revolving about the x-axis.

Thanks for anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 4):

The graph, as you surmised, of $y=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ is the upper half of the semicircle with center at $(0,0)$ and radius $a$. (Square both sides to get $y^2 = a^2-x^2$, or $x^2+y^2=a^2$, the equation of the circle described; since $y\geq 0$, it's the upper half). (Of course, you need $|a|\geq 2$ for your limits to make sense).

The formula for the length of the graph of $y=f(x)$ from $x=r$ to $x=s$ is
$$\mathrm{Arc\ Length} = \int_r^s \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}
\,dx.$$
So here, you have $y=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$, so take the derivative, square, plug it into the formula, that will give the arc length.

For the area of the surface, I don't know which formula you know. The one I know is that the area is given by
$$\mathrm{Area} = \int_r^s 2\pi f(x)\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\,dx.$$

**Added.** So, since you've essentially worked it out: if $|a|\gt 2$ (so we don't have to worry about the derivative and the curve being defined over the entire interval $[-2,1]$), we have
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}.$$
So
$$ 1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 = 1 + \frac{x^2}{a^2-x^2} = \frac{a^2}{a^2-x^2}.$$
So for arc length, we have:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Arc\ Length} &= \int_{-2}^1 \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\,dx \\
&= \int_{-2}^1 \sqrt{\frac{a^2}{a^2-x^2}}\,dx\\
&= \int_{-2}^1 \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\,dx\\
&= a\int_{-2}^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\\
&= a\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\Biggm|_{-2}^1\\
&= a\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) - a\arcsin\left(\frac{-2}{a}\right)\\
&= a\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{a}\right) + a\arcsin\left(\frac{2}{a}\right).
\end{align*}
For the surface area, you have:
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Surface\ Area} &= \int_{-2}^1 2\pi f(x)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}\,dx\\
&= 2\pi \int_{-2}^1 \sqrt{a^2-x^2}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)\,dx\\
&= 2\pi a \int_{-2}^1 \,dx = 2\pi a(1-(-2)) = 6\pi a.
\end{align*}
If $a=2$, then the two integrals are improper and you need to use limits, but you'll end up with the same answer in both cases. If $0\lt a\lt 2$, the integrals are not well-defined (but then neither is the problem).

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Yes, you are correct, my derivative was incorrect.  I will work further with this information and report back, thanks.

Comment: (answered my own question)

Comment: @Finzz: No, the arc length formula doesn't have the $2\pi x$ in it. That factor comes from estimating the surface area of a "cylinder" you get by rotating around the $x$ axis. I can give you a derivation of the formulas if you prefer, though I suspect your textbook will have it.

Comment: Yeah I got mixed up between Area and Arc Length.

Comment: So instead of the 1 + (dy/dx)^2 under the radical it is a + (dy/dx)^2?

Comment: @Finzz: I put in $a$ because *you* had $a$, to point out the mistake in the computation. By my count, it should be $1$ in both formulas. Also, note that$$1 + \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 = 1 + \frac{x^2}{a^2-x^2} = \frac{a^2}{a^2-x^2}$$inside the radical, so that should make life much simpler.

Comment: @Arturo:  Thanks for explaining, it helps a lot.  Could you show how you got from the 1 + with x^2 on top to the a^2 on top?

Comment: @Finzz:Just algebra:$$1 + \frac{x^2}{a^2-x^2} = \frac{a^2-x^2}{a^2-x^2}+\frac{x^2}{a^2-x^2} = \frac{a^2-x^2+x^2}{a^2-x^2} = \frac{a^2}{a^2-x^2}.$$

Comment: Alright, so should I end up with something like this for arc length:              a*arcsin($\frac{1}{a}$)+C$ - lim(b approach -2 from neg. side$(a(arcsin($\frac{b}{a})))+C$  and |a| > 2$

Comment: @Finzz: You are getting confused between my $a$ in the formula (which was merely a random letter) and the $a$ in *your* problem. Your integral should go from $-2$ to $1$, not from $a$ to $b$.  Let me change my a's and b's to $r$ and $s$. Sorry for the confusion that caused; your integral should be a proper integral, so there will be no need to invoke limits. Just take it from $-2$ to $1$ (assuming that $|a|\gt 2$, of course).

Comment: Alright, you had said "for your limits to make sense" so I got confused, looking at $a^2-x^2$ I figured, oh, I must limit that since, x is approaching -2 but now I see.

Comment: @Finzz: I said "for your limits to make sense" because if you are looking at, say, the circle of radius $1$ (i.e., $a=1$), then it would not make sense to talk about the arc length from $x=-2$ to $x=1$ (since the curve does not extend all the way to $x=-2$). Again, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Alright so was I still correct in solving that for a*arcsin(x/a)+C from -2 to 1 or no?

Comment: Do the a's get left in there or do they get changed as x does?

Comment: @Arturo, also I should be using $2\pi(y)$ and not $2\pi(x)$, right?

Comment: @Finzz: Sorry, but I went to bed shortly after my last comment last night. I'll check the answers shortly.

Comment: @Finzz: Yes, because we are rotating around the $x$-axis, you use $2\pi y = 2\pi f(x)$; sorry about that.